# What's the best way to inject a React component into another React component? Or should I bother?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, reactjs

While working on my first large React application, I started feeling uneasy about the tight coupling of nested components, especially when writing unit tests.

If is a high-level component, and its render function returns `<div><Bar><Baz /></Bar></div>`, I would like to be able to test Foo, Bar, and Baz in isolation.

I searched for advice but didn't find any. So, on my own, I came up with two methods of injection: factory functions and via the outer component's properties. (I am not talking about Children. I'm talking about "baked in" dependencies--the sort people usually import via require or import statements.

### Properties

```
const Baz = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <p>Inner</p>;
  }
});

const Foo = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const Bar = this.props.innerComponent;
    return <Bar />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo innerComponent={Baz} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

### Factory

```
const Baz = React.createClass({
 render() {
   return <p>Inner</p>;
 }
});

const fooFactory = innerComponent => {
  return  React.createClass({
    render() {
      const Bar = innerComponent;
      return <Bar />;
   }
 });
};

const Foo = fooFactory(Baz);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo innerComponent={Baz} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Or am I just taking decoupling too far? I see almost no one else doing this in any tutorials or examples.

Would you be inclined to inject components sometimes but not other times? In what circumstances? And, if you did it, would you use one of the above techniques or do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern you'll see from time to time when there is a run-time necessity for specifying a component *type* which the component it's passed to will instantiate itself; for example, [the React `TransitionGroup` component takes such a property](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#rendering-a-different-component) called `component`:

> By default `ReactTransitionGroup` renders as a `span`. You can change this behavior by providing a `component` prop. For example, here's how you would render a `<ul>`:
>
> ```
> <ReactTransitionGroup component="ul">
>   ...
> </ReactTransitionGroup>
> ```
>
> Every DOM component that React can render is available for use. However, `component` does not need to be a DOM component. It can be any React component you want; even ones you've written yourself! Just write `component={List}` and your component will receive `this.props.children`.

It's less common to use this pattern for the user-specified *contents* of a component, since this is solved more elegantly by `this.props.children`.

However, as far as testing is concerned, the common solution is simply to export each component separately and test it in isolation. If a high-level component composes them in a certain way, all you really need to test is that they are composed properly, since the components are also tested individually.

There is a common pattern of separating "smart" and "dumb" components; dumb components simply render what they're given, and are very easily unit tested. Smart components may fetch data (e.g. via Ajax, or from a flux store), compose specific dumb components, or make other "decisions," and can be tougher to test—but again, since the dumb components are already tested, ideally you can just check that the smart component behaves correctly and renders the right thing.

To use your example, it's `Foo`'s *job* to render `<div><Bar><Baz /></Bar></div>`; it's a smart component, and the test should ensure that it renders exactly that. `Bar`'s job, however, is to render its children, and is more easily tested.

You also have the ability to mock out a component [with `TestUtils.mockComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#mockcomponent).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. You wouldn't generally decouple a factory function fro whatever it is it's making, because it's *job* is to make that thing.

Comment: @MarcusGeduld Right. That sort of dependency inversion is useful sometimes, but just over-engineering others.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mochajs](https://mochajs.org/). This testing framework overrides `import` / `require`, which solves your problem.

It does mean that your subcomponents need to be written as ECMA 6 or NodeJS modules, though - but that really just means they need to be in separate source files.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip. Though it would be nice to not be shackled to a particular testing framework. 

It would also be nice, I think, to have looser coupling of components in general.